# How long does it takes for arduino to reach main()?

Tags: attiny85

I am trying to emulate the behavior of a circuit using an Attiny85

This is the result I got so far:

[image]

In the picture above, D2 is VCC, D4, D5 and D6 are outputs of the circuit I am trying to emulate. D7 is the output of Attiny85

The code I am using is:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000L
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main() {

  DDRB = 0b00001000;

  PORTB = 0b00001000;
  _delay_ms(5);

  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(5);
  PORTB = 0b00001000;
  _delay_ms(5);

  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(5);

  _delay_ms(5);

  while(1)
  {  
     PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(1);
     PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(1);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

According to this, it takes roughly 64ms from powerup until it actually run the main program.

Is there any reason for such a delay? How can I reduce it somehow (ideally to 20ms or less)?

Comment: do you use a bootloader or you program it over ISP?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - yes, I programmed over a ISP (usbtiny) to make sure the bootloader is not active

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ATtiny85 has a built-in delay counter that keeps the MCU in reset
mode for some time after the power is applied. This seems to be intended
as a wait for the clock and power to be stabilized. The length of this
delay depends on your selected clock source, and is somewhat
configurable with the fuses.

According to your code, your MCU is clocked at 8 MHz. I assume you
are then using the internal RC oscillator as a clock source. If this is
the case, you have three choices for the startup delay:

- 20 CPU cycles
- 20 CPU cycles + 4 ms
- 20 CPU cycles + 64 ms

The latter is recommended if your power rises slowly, and is the default
configuration in which these MCUs are shipped. If you power level rises
fast, you may want to select a shorter delay by programming the SUT
fuses. See the datasheet for details (section System Clock and Clock
Options → Clock Sources → Calibrated Internal Oscillator).

Comment: You are right - my L fuse was programmed as 0xE1 (PLL clock, 64ms delay). I changed it to 0xD2 (Internal clock, 8Mhz, 4ms delay) and it worked